# How to deactive java error popup

Tags: java, popup

when I try to connect a qc server through jacob sometimes java stops to working and a get a error popup window with message "Java(TM) Platform SE binary doesn't work", where I can close the window or run a debug tool.

My tool has to run all the time. So my idea is to write a second script that rerun my tool always if it is down. But to do this i must "tell" java to not popup any window if a problem occur again or when java just stop to work.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Try adding these options to the command line: `-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.awt.headlesslib=true` -- argh, `true`, not `false`, sorry

Comment: Thank you, i will add these options to the command line. This is a sporadic error so I can give at the earliest tomorrow a feedback :)